# Creating functions in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, function, t-sql, parameters

I'm trying to create a function that will print game information when the user enters a starting date and an ending date as a parameter. It will show the game information if the game date is between the starting and end date. I decided to use a table valued function.

So far I have:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_gamedate
    (@InputStartDate DATETIME, 
     @InputEndDate DATETIME)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
    RETURN 
        (SELECT * 
         FROM Game 
         WHERE Game.[Date] Between @StartDate AND @EndDate)
```

The error I get when I try to run this is

> Must declare the scalar variable "@StartDate".

I'm confused as to what I would declare the `@startdate` and `@enddate` as and where in the statement to declare it. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The **parameter** is called `@InputStartDate`, but in the code, you use `@StartDate` - make up your mind!

Try this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_gamedate
    (@InputStartDate DATETIME,   <--------+
     @InputEndDate DATETIME)              | these two need to MATCH!
RETURNS TABLE                             | 
AS                                        |
    RETURN                                | 
        (SELECT *                         |
         FROM Game                        |
         WHERE Game.[Date] Between @InputStartDate AND @InputEndDate)
```

If you name your **parameter** `@InputStartDate`, then you *must use* the same name in your T-SQL statement!